# Need to compare 2 generic list of same type based on dynamic columns/fields that will be know at run time

Tags: c#, linq

I want to compare 2 generic list of same type based on multiple columns/fields that will be know at runtime. Need to get the rows from second list that are not in first list by matching given fields.

Scenario :

```
public static void PerformCrudOperation<T>(List<T> sourceList, List<T> newList, 
    String [] columnNames) where T : class
{
    // list from sourceList that are not part of newList, matching criteria columnNames
}
```

for example we have 2 list of type employee (but can be any type, so need a generic solution)

```
class Employee
{
    public Int32 EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; } 
    public String FirstName { get; set; } 
    public String Title { get; set; } 
    public String City { get; set; } 
    public String StatusFlag { get; set; } 
}
List<Employee> SourceList = new List<Employee>();
List<Employee> NewList = new List<Employee>();
```

SourceList is in memory data.

NewList is what user will provide, with some new records, some modified and some delete(for delete user set StatusFlag to delete).

Now keys will be given by use e.g. EmployeeID and LastName ( but he can also add FirtName).

Objective :-1. To find out the rows that need to be delete from SourceList\
            2. To find out the new row to insert (rows that are not in SourceList by matching EmployeeID and LastName in both list)
            3. Modified row

[Please see this for more information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LozpV.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please, share your code

Comment: Hi @PavelAnikhouski I want to compare 2 generic list based on some columns that are not know at compile time will be selected by user. So need to match the values from both the list based on that columns list.

Comment: `bool listsAreEqual = sourceList == null ? newList == null : newList != null && sourceList.SequenceEqual(newList);`

Comment: *"based on multiple columns/fields that will be know at runtime"* Without using reflection, which defeats the purpose of generics, you'll need to constrain `T` to a type or interface that contains the fields you want to compare.

Comment: @RufusL Thanks for reply, But I want to compare some fields not all object

Comment: @RufusL The issue I not sure on which column/fields use want to compare list, coulmn/fields name will received from user

Comment: Is the user passing you a generic comparison method that can be used, or just strings representing the fields, or something else? If they just pass a string representing a property name, like "Id", then reflection will likely be the only option. But if they pass a method, like `Func<T, bool>`, then you can just use that for the comparison.

Comment: @RufusL User will pass columns name e.g. ID, LastName like (ID,LastName)

Comment: How do you determine a modified row based on a list of properties? It seems like you'd have to know if the new item was a modification or an insertion, but how would you know?

Comment: So idea is if combination of (ID and LastName) value not present in source list then, it will consider as new entry. If values are present then we can compare the whole entry if not matched then considered as modified or updated record.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to iterate over all the properties for both items and determine what you want to do when specific properties match (or don't match).

Here's a simple example that may help:

```
public static void PerformCrudOperation<T>(List<T> sourceList, List<T> newList,
    string[] columnNames) where T : class
{
    // Get a list of ALL the properties for the type
    List<PropertyInfo> props = typeof(T).GetProperties().ToList();

    // Get a list of just the properties from the column names array
    List<PropertyInfo> cols = props
        .Where(prop => columnNames.Contains(prop.Name)).ToList();

    // Get all items from source that don't have a corresponding item  
    // in newList that has all matching fields specified in columnNames
    var itemsToRemove = sourceList
        .Where(srcItem => !newList.Any(newItem => cols.All(col =>
            col.GetValue(srcItem) == col.GetValue(newItem))))
        .ToList();

    // Add any items that are in newList but don't 
    // have all colProps matching in sourceList
    var itemsToAdd = newList
        .Where(newItem => !sourceList.Any(srcItem => props.All(propInfo =>
            propInfo.GetValue(srcItem) == propInfo.GetValue(newItem))))
        .ToList();

    // Get all items from newList that have matching colProps in sourceList but 
    // different values for other properties
    var itemsToUpdate = newList
        .Where(newItem => sourceList.Any(srcItem =>
            cols.All(col => col.GetValue(newItem) == col.GetValue(srcItem)) &&
            props.Any(prop => prop.GetValue(newItem) != prop.GetValue(srcItem))))
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Hi @rufus thanks for reply, the solution you have provided is not given the desired output. But yeah we want something like that,seems like column conditions are not working. I have attached a image for more info, please check. Thanks again.